# How to change permission of jar packaged by maven? I am using maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using maven assembly plugin to package a jar with all dependencies. But the jar file is not executable. How can I change the permission of the jar?

```
-rw-r--r--  1 e17490  ADPROD\Domain Users  12072889 Nov 12 14:16 com-foo-bar.jar
```

Pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>foo.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>        
      </plugin>
```

Comment: A jar can be executable without its file having the executable flag. What matters is what it **contains**. Read the tutorial to know what an executable jar is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't try executing with executable flag off. Seems to work.

Answer (score 12):

Use `maven:exec`   plugin to execute `chmod`

for example

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${org.codehaus.mojo.version}</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
            <id>script-chmod</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>chmod</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>+x</argument>
                    <argument>your-assembled-jar.jar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This worked great! I made a change to the phase so it ran at <phase>compile</phase> time after any resources may have been newly copied to the output directory. For the arguments, for my use case, I had three: <argument>-R</argument> <argument>+x</argument> <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}</argument>. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A Jar file can be executed on Linux if there is Java support. Some distributions already come with such a configuration. All you need to do is to threat jar files as if they were any executable, such as a compiled program or a script:

```
chmod 700 myJar.jar
./myJar.jar
```

So the question does make sense.

You need to be aware that this solution may be not portable across platforms.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478495/how-do-i-set-directory-permissions-in-maven-output), you need to use the following on Maven:

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/web</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>some_dir</include>
      </includes>
      <outputDirectory>web</outputDirectory>
      <fileMode>0777</fileMode>
      <directoryMode>0777</directoryMode>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
```

if that does not work, you can also call the [chmod Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chmod.html) from Maven using the [AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/):

`<chmod file="${dist}/start.sh" perm="ugo+rx"/>`